# How to find the ideal path done inside a given shape in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, libgdx

I'm trying to make an android/libgdx game in which for every level you have a different shape as a png, and you have to drag your finger inside the shape and try to be as close as the ideal path created after the shape. At the end of the level the game will show you in a percentage how close you were from the ideal path.

My question is how can I find the ideal way that the player has to follow? Is there any function that i can use to find out the array of points created after the shape?

My problem is that the shape width is different along the way, so I can't use the pixels path. I already have an algorithm which gives me the array of points from the path of the player so I have to compare it with the ideal one.

If you have any ideas of any algorithm or functions that can help please let me know.

Example of shape inside the game:

[image]

Comment: This site isn't designed for open ended questions like this, so you'll probably get better advice on a forum. I would make a distance field version of the image. Store the touch points on another bitmap. Multiply the two bitmaps to calculate  the score.

Comment: Draw the shape in your game, and you should get it nomatter the resolution. Or take the viewport that does not distort/stretch the image, and you could use predefined physics sensors / touch points to acheive it.

Comment: I want to find a way using the pngs. Ca you be more specific regarding the viewport?